# (PDO) function that prepares and executes query

Tags: php, pdo

The following is what i have so far. but it doesnt output anything. I dont get what im doing wrong. I already have a connect function which is called as the page constructs

```
class dataview extends PDO
    {
    public $dbh;
    function prep($querytoprepare = null, $parameters = null)
        {
        $query = $this->dbh->prepare($querytoprepare);
        if($parameters === null)
             {
             $query->execute();
             }
        else
             {
             $query->execute($parameters);      
             }
             $query->fetchAll();

        }  
        function getData()
        {
        $query = prep("SELECT * FROM table");
        $table = "<table>";
        foreach($query as $result
             {
             $table .= "<tr><td>" . $result['product_id'] . "</td><td>" . $result['naam'] . "</td><td>&#8364;" . $result['prijs'] . "</td></tr>";
             }
        $table .="</table>";
        echo $table;
        }
    }
$x = new dataview();
$x->getData();
```

Comment: (1) Your block level indentation is super awful. (2) You are not invoking the method correctly, use `$this->prep()`. (3) And you are not `return`ing the resultset from the `->fetchAll()` call. (4) The  `if($parameters === null)` test is redundant.

Comment: I dont get what you mean with point #4. I need to check if the execute  function has parameters right??

Comment: and also at #1 yep in the post it is but im still trying to get used to stackoverflow :)

Comment: In regards to #4, you don't need to check that. Just pass null or an empty array. The execute method deals with zero parameters already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prep function does not returns with a thing.
That should end with

```
       return $query->fetchAll();
```

And you should call prep function like this:

```
       $query = $this->prep(" ... ");
```

Comment: Oh i totally forgot to use $this......, Thanks alot Kovge